# Laravel image path stored as .tmp

Tags: laravel, image, php-7.3

I'm trying to store images in the database:

```
   public function update(Request $request, $id)
   {

       if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
           $image = $request->file('image');
           $filename = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
           $path = 'storage/images/' . $filename;
           Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize(300, 300)->save($path);
       }

       $this->productservice->update($request, $id);


       return redirect()->back()->with('status', 'Product has been updated succesfully');
   }
```

I've done that before in Laravel and never had problems with it. I'm using Repository-Service pattern this time although  not sure if that's a cause of the problem somehow.
The imaged itself is moved in the right folder, however the path in the database is:

```
C:\xampp\tmp\php596F.tmp
```

I've googled/checked other suggestions on stackoverflow to this problem, but none of them worked.

**Update**
silly me, I should have removed image from model's fillables, it wasn't even saving most of the time anything.

Comment: Unfortunately, same outcome.

Comment: Don't use getRealPath tho

Comment: @sta what a bad advice?..

Comment: im not done yet hahaha

Comment: Validate the `image` before upload it

Comment: Nothing has helped so far, guys.

Comment: You are currently updating the value from `$request`, which is the image value always in C:\xampp\tmp\ folder. You need to do like this `$this->productservice->update(['column_name_in_your_db' => $path], $id);`

Comment: you know what I mean right?? you try to dd the `$request->file('image')` , it'll return the temp path.

Comment: @StevanLai didn't work, passed type is array and it expects expects instance of Illuminate\Http\Request

Answer (score 1):

**Cause** : The Problem is that your **Request** Data hasn't changed while you uploaded the picture. So `image` still contains **tmpdata**.

---

**How to fix** : Make sure that you added `multipart/form-data` on your `form`. Make a validation in your controller to ensure that the uploaded file is an **image**, like this :

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
   {

     $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif',
       ]);

       if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
           $image = $request->file('image');
           $filename = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
           $path = 'storage/images/' . $filename;
           Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize(300, 300)->save($path);
           $request->replace(['image' => $path]);
       }

       //$request['image'] = $filename;
       

       $this->productservice->update($request, $id);

       return redirect()->back()->with('status', 'Product has been updated succesfully');
   }
```

Comment: $this->productservice->update() expects instance of Illuminate\Http\Request and array is passed, so wouldn't work.

Comment: Would you try again?

Comment: Still stored as tmp

Comment: Give the output of `dd($request->file('image'));`?

Comment: pathname: "C:\xampp\tmp\php4DDE.tmp"

Comment: If still doesn't work try this `$request->merge([ 'image' => $path]);`

Comment: Did you add `multipart/form-data` on your form?

Answer (score 0):

silly me, I should have removed image from model's fillables, it wasn't even saving most of the time anything.

Answer (score 0):

use `->save()` method.

```
 $this->productservice->save($request, $id);
```